# Building mutliple C# solutions at a once from command line with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, build, build-process, build-automation

There are 20 to 30 C# solutions in one root folder. I would like to automate the build of  all these solutions at a once using Visual Studio Command prompt.

I tried MSBUILD and CSC. But i didn't get the way automatically to build all the solutions resided in a folder.

Comment: Loop the over the solutions in batch (or PowerShell) and build each on in turn, perhaps? Although that's still very primitive ..

Answer (score 2):

Use this syntax:

```
MSBUILD [projectfile]
```

[MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx)

To build all, you could just create a simple batch file, *buildall.bat* or whatever.

```
MSBUILD project1.csproj
MSBUILD project2.csproj
... etc
pause
```

Comment: @pst I wasn't sure if that was the actual question; was sort of assuming most people know what a batch file is.

Comment: +1 It's also important to setup the environment variables as the shortcut VS shells do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280559/how-to-get-cmd-line-build-command-for-vs-solution/280584#280584

Comment: @dbaseman: There are many projects with dependencies associated in a single solution. Like these i've 20-30 solutions. Each solution is present in a each folder. Like these I've 30 folders in a main root folder. now i want to build all these solutions at a once. How can i do?

Comment: @sukumar do you mean 20-30 *solutions* (.sln) or *projects* (.csproj)?  You should be targeting the latter, just ignore the solution files.  The dependencies should all be contained in the .csproj file (assuming you've set them up correctly in VS), so *MSBUILD* should be able to resolve them.  Just using `MSBUILD [filename].csproj` -- try this with one or two of the projects first, from the command prompt, and see if it works, or if there are errors.